# Show Facebook Albums in Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, plugins, gallery

Is there a way to (automagically) show the Albums on a Facebook Fansite on a Wordpress page? I know that there are some plugins, but none of them are working.

I've read all instructions carefully, but every plugin either shows nothing or is loading endlessly the albums. Are there some recent changes from Facebook so that this plugins are not working anymore?

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: With no way to know which plugins you've tried or how, there's not much to go on.

Comment: i've tried nearly every plugin, like: facebook album, facebook album sync, DUB facebook albums, srizon facebook album, facebook vinyl, facebook photo fetcher, etc. ... always the same. either nothing or endless loading

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook Graph API to get the details required. Though you may have to build it into a plugin or into a short-code.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/YOURPAGEID?fields=albums.fields(photos)
```

will output the JSON list of albums and pictures within each. You can build a list as you see fit with this (after translating into array).

*EDIT*

Try this out...

1) Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`

2) In the text box at the top (beside GET), enter `/me/accounts` and click on submit. This should change the output below.

3) Find the Facebook page you are looking for and click on it ID (**"id": "xxxx7105752xxxx"**). Once that is done you should see in the request box the url changes to ***/xxxx7105752xxxx*** (xxxx7105752xxxx being the page ID).

4) On the left of the result box, select the nodes needed. Click on the + sign (under the id) and select "albums" under "connections".

5) Still in the left side, click on the + sign immediatley under the "albums ->" link selected and find "photos" under "connections". Hit the submit button. This should build you a JSON reply under for albums and pictures under each album.

6) to use this link, copy out what you have in your request URL and use as:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/xxxx7105752xxxx?fields=albums.fields(photos)
```

If you paste this in a browser url bar it should give you the same JSON response.

Using this you can request any data you want from facebook and have the results in JSON.

Comment: this outputs "code: 2500, Subfields are not supported by albums"

Answer (score 0):

Try following to get the public albums of a page-

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>/albums?fields=photos
```

[Example](http://graph.facebook.com/Shadowfax.Sahil/albums?fields=photos)

Comment: thanks. there is no data shown. this url gives me `data: []` ... is it possible that the albums are not activated for the public or anything similar? but the albums are visible on the facebook page...

Comment: That means the albums is not public. If its your page- you can use the page access token with the above url just like: `&access_token=` . To get the page access token, call `/me/account?fields=accesstoken` (need permission `manage_pages`). (The example is giving the output, right?)

Comment: so the pictures could be not public even if the pictures are visible for everyone (on the facebook site)? `graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/me/account?fields=accesstoken` gives me an error like `Unknown path components: /me/account`

Comment: I dont think so! May be you should check your page settings.

Comment: ok. do you know which settings exactly? i'm a manager of a facebook fanpage... in case this helps..

Comment: You can check that yourself, see the edit settings button and see if the posts are public. If yes, then the above query must work. At least it works in my case. I really cant help you without looking your actual case. Good luck

Comment: thanks for your help. now i know what causes the problem. the fanpage was visible to all user aged above 17... so it was a demographic problem. when i make the fan page visible to all user, all of the albums could be fetched by wordpress! cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a plugin years ago. It's working just fine. There were some days when it stopped working due to changes made by Facebook but I fixed them as soon as it was reported.
Here's the link to the plugin
[Srizon Facebook Album](https://wordpress.org/plugins/srizon-facebook-album/)